# Draw perpendicular to TikZ Node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Often, when drawing block diagrams i want to add an 'input' to a node with a perpendicular line (drawn in red below).

Is there a way to achieve this in a robust way without using calc, etc.? Ideally i want to use something like `\draw (input) -| (node)`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum height=4cm,minimum width=1cm] (node) at (0,0) {ABC};
\draw[->] (-2,1) node[anchor=east] {Some input 1} -- (node);
\draw[->,red] (-2,-1) node[anchor=east] {Some input 2} -- +(1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `-|` and `|-` operators to form coordinates. Here, you could provide the *y* value explicity with `n.east` by naming the node containing `Some input 2` as `n`. Another way is to use the `to` path operation which automatically sets `\tikztostart` to the start coordinate of the `to` operation:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=1cm] (node) at (0,0) {ABC};
\draw[->] (-2,1) node[anchor=east] {Some input 1} -- (node);
\draw[->, red] (-2,-1) node[anchor=east] {Some input 2}
  to (\tikztostart -| node.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To address some comments, the following shows that the problem is not well-defined with “general shapes”:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, minimum height=2cm,
      rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle west arc=concave] (n) {Some stuff};
\node[circle, inner sep=1.5pt] (foo) at (n.west) {foo};
\draw[red!60!black, ->]
  let \p1=($(n.north)-(n.center)$) in
  (foo) foreach \angle in {-90, -75, ..., 90} { edge +(\angle:\y1) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## But what if?..

So, you have a rotated rectangular node and still want to play? The Ti*k*Z `calc` library can orthogonally project a point *p* on a line *(ab)* with its `($(a)!(p)!(b)$)` syntax:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, rotate=30] (n) {Some stuff};
\node[draw] (foo) at (-1,0.5) {foo bar};
\foreach \anch in {270, 300, 320, 330, 337, 350} {
  \draw[very thin, ->] (foo.\anch)  --
    ($(n.north west)!(foo.\anch)!(n.north east)$);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Luckily, the desired point on the node border is just vertical down. -Do you have any suggestions for a solution, if the ABC node is not rectangular - e.g. a circle?

Comment: Would really be interesting to extend the idea to arbitrary node shapes.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Well, if the ABC node is a circle, a simple `-- (node)` is enough because lines that go through the center of a circle are perpendicular to the circle. For any shape in general, I'm afraid I don't have much to offer, except to say this is not well defined: there can very well be several points that satisfy the perpendicularity condition.

Comment: But `-- (node)` will not go horizontal to the circle. See also my answer.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Right, but the question title says “perpendicular to TikZ node”, not “horizontal.” :-)

Comment: @hpekristiansen I added an example where there is an infinite number of points on the shape *visible* border that satisfy the perpendicularity condition.

Comment: I mistakenly read horizontal because of the desired `-|` syntax. I guess that case can be solved cumbersomely by `intersections` like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82010/connecting-to-a-node-towards-a-point-other-than-the-center . (I have no real need)

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes, I think that would work.

Answer (score 8):

Complementary to the very good answer from frougon, if you don't want to use the `\tikztostart` macro (which is perfectly fine), you can also name the node containing *Some input 2* (here, by `aux`) and use this name in the construction of the intersecting point `(aux-|node.west)`. This is sometime useful when drawing multiple broken lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,minimum height=4cm,minimum width=1cm] (node) at (0,0) {ABC};
        \draw[->] (-2,1) node[anchor=east] {Some input 1} -- (node);
        \draw[->,red] (-2,-1) node[anchor=east] (aux) {Some input 2} -- (aux-|node.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Answer (score 4):

This is a stupid answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}        
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=1cm] (node) at (0,0) {ABC};
\draw[<-] (node.120) -- +(-2,0) node[anchor=east] {Some input 1};
\draw[<-] (node.150) -- +(-2,0) node[anchor=east] {Some input 2};
\draw[<-] (node.190) -- +(-2,0) node[anchor=east] {Some input 3};
\draw[<-] (node.240) -- +(-2,0) node[anchor=east] {Some input 4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Input nodes pointing horizontal to circle]

This method works, even if the "ABC" node is not rectangular. -but the huge problem is that the position of the input node is not set by an explicit coordinate.